# Duplicate layer with opacity

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have a layer with color where I have decreased the opacity. I would like to duplicate the layer, and keep the color as it appears now due to the decreased opacity, but I would like the new layer to not be semi-transparent. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

### Solid Color Layer

- Duplicate the layer
- Double click the thumbnail to edit it
- Get the **Eyedropper** tool and click the semi transparent layer to get the
  color
- Change the duplicated layer opacity to 100%

[image]

### Regular layer filled with a color

- Duplicate the layer
- Click the **Lock Transparent Pixels** layer icon
- Get the **Eyedropper** tool and click the semi transparent layer to get the
  color
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to fill the layer content with the foreground color
- Change the duplicated layer opacity to 100%

[image]

Comment: Double-clicking on the thumbnail opens up the Layer Style window

Answer (score 0):

The new color is the underlying image filtered by the partially transparent layer. Duplicate the transparent layer, the needed underlying layers and merge them. Use the original layers to make the needed selections if you have to delete something from the merged layer.

An example:

[image]

The triangle has got its color from solid yellow fill and blending with the underlying gradient layer.

Both layers are duplicated and merged. The emptiness around the original triangle is selected with the magic wand and the exessive gradient around the triangle has been deleted with that selection in the merged layer. The result is moved aside to the right:

[image]

Comment: In this scenario, you could make a selection from the layer and then use a deep copy `Edit > Copy Merged` then paste it back into the document. If you wanted to keep it slightly more editable, I guess you could duplicate just be background `Layer > New > Layer via copy` and then you would have 2 layers to manage.